# Problem with Tcolorbox and Ref

Tags: tcolorbox, books, ref

About this code, I'd like something like that

[image: Corollary]

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight,english]{minitoc}

% (Re)newcommands

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}


% New Theorems

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection] {goldtheorem}{Theorem}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---},#1,}{th}

% New Corollaries

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection, use counter from=goldtheorem] {goldcorolth}{Corollary of \Thref{th:#2} --- }{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---},#1,}{th}

\newenvironment{statement}[1]{\textsc{Statement}$\:\:\blacktriangleright\:\:${#1}}

% New refs

\newcommand{\Thref}[1]{Theorem \ref{th:#1}}

\newcommand{\Propref}[1]{Proposition \ref{prop:#1}}

\newcommand{\Defref}[1]{Definition \ref{def:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorTref}[1]{Corollary \ref{th:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorLref}[1]{Corollary \ref{lem:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorPref}[1]{Corollary \ref{prop:#1}}

\newcommand{\Obsref}[1]{Observation \ref{obs:#1}}

\newcommand{\Lemref}[1]{Lemma \ref{lem:#1}}


\begin{document}

\title{\Huge\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Proof Book}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\maketitle

\dominitoc

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=\Huge{Contents},colframe=orange,colback=Silver!75,colbacktitle=Gold1,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=red,attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm, frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame]([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east) -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west) -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east) -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- cycle;} }] %\csname @starttoc\endcsname{toc} 
\makeatletter \@starttoc{toc} \makeatother
\end{tcolorbox}

%\tableofcontents

\part[First Example Part]{\Huge\textcolor{red}{First Example Part}}

\chapter[Goldboxed Theorems]{\huge Goldboxed Theorems}
\minitoc
\mtcskip

\section[Some theorem for proof]{\Large Some theorem for proof}

\section{Added of the Corollaries}

\begin{goldtheorem}{A Theorem}{T1}
\begin{statement}

\end{statement}
\end{goldtheorem}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}

\noindent\begin{goldcorolth}{A Corollary} {CorolT}{T1}

\end{goldcorolth}
But I'd like to have this:

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Corollary of Theorem 1.2.0.1 --- 1.2.0.2 --- A Corollary}, nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---}]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make complete but *small* example. Your code contains lot of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: I authorize you to delete the irrelevant things

Comment: I edited my code. I pray you to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a new tcolorbox option `theorem ref=<label>` is provided.

- Definition: `\tcbset{theorem ref/.initial}`
- Usage in declaration of `goldcorolth` env:

  ```tex
  % before
  \newtcbtheorem[...]{goldcorolth}{Corollary of \Thref{th:#2} --- }
  % after
  \newtcbtheorem[...]{goldcorolth}
    {Corollary of \Thref{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/theorem ref}} --- }
  ```
- Usage in use of `goldcorolth` env:

  ```tex
  \begin{goldcorolth}[theorem ref=T1]{A Corollary}{CorolT}
      <body>
  \end{goldcorolth}
  ```

Some more words:

- Since `\Thref` is defined by `\newcommand{\Thref}[1]{Theorem \ref{th:#1}}`, when used you don't need the `th:` in its argument. That says, use `\Thref{<label>}` instead of `\Thref{th:<label>}`.
- `\newtheorem` always defines a new theorem environment that takes one optional and two mandatory arguments, hence the attempt to pass `goldcorolth` a third mandatory argument (`\begin{goldcorolth}{A Corollary} {CorolT}{T1}`) is invalid.
- Hence I use key-value options to receive and store extra info, and use it in the title. Here the passed value is stored directly in the key `/tcb/theorem ref`. One can also store it in a/an (explicit) macro, e.g.

  ```tex
  \makeatletter
  \tcbset{theorem ref/.store in=\tcb@theo@ref}
  \newtcbtheorem[...]{goldcorolth}{Corollary of \Thref{\tcb@theo@ref} --- }{...}{th}
  \makeatother
  ```
- Providing a new `\newtheorem`-like command that defines theorem env accepting more than two mandatory args is possible, but requires knowledge of internals of tcolorbox theorem macros.

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage[tight,english]{minitoc}

% (Re)newcommands

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}


% New Theorems

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection] {goldtheorem}{Theorem}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---},#1,}{th}

% New Corollaries

\tcbset{
  theorem ref/.initial=,
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection, use counter from=goldtheorem] {goldcorolth}{Corollary of \Thref{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/theorem ref}} --- }{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---},theorem ref=,#1,}{th}

\newenvironment{statement}[1]{\textsc{Statement}$\:\:\blacktriangleright\:\:${#1}}

% New refs

\newcommand{\Thref}[1]{Theorem \ref{th:#1}}

\newcommand{\Propref}[1]{Proposition \ref{prop:#1}}

\newcommand{\Defref}[1]{Definition \ref{def:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorTref}[1]{Corollary \ref{th:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorLref}[1]{Corollary \ref{lem:#1}}

\newcommand{\CorPref}[1]{Corollary \ref{prop:#1}}

\newcommand{\Obsref}[1]{Observation \ref{obs:#1}}

\newcommand{\Lemref}[1]{Lemma \ref{lem:#1}}


\begin{document}

\chapter[Goldboxed Theorems]{\huge Goldboxed Theorems}
%\minitoc
%\mtcskip

\section[Some theorem for proof]{\Large Some theorem for proof}

\section{Added of the Corollaries}

\begin{goldtheorem}{A Theorem}{T1}
\begin{statement}

\end{statement}
\end{goldtheorem}
\begin{proof}
Its Proof.
\end{proof}

\noindent\begin{goldcorolth}[theorem ref=T1]{A Corollary}{CorolT}%{T1}
Corollary body
\end{goldcorolth}
But I'd like to have this:

\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Corollary of Theorem 1.2.0.1 --- 1.2.0.2 --- A Corollary}, nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,enhanced,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=Gold1!10!white,bottom color=Gold1!10!white, middle color=Gold1!50!yellow,},colframe=red,fuzzy halo=1pt with Gold1,description color = black, coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign={\ ---}]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You completely solved my problem, Thank you very much, That's perfect!